# Autolayout for iPad portrait and landscape separately iOS8

Tags: ios, autolayout

I have about 3 or 4 buttons on a view. They have vertical spacing. I want something like this:

In portrait 
those spacings = 100

In landscape those spacings = 200

How can I achieve this with autolayout by Interface Builder

Comment: check out this tutorial: http://mathewsanders.com/designing-adaptive-layouts-for-iphone-6-plus/

Comment: I understand what your link share. But with iPad it has no different size classes.

Comment: You can use IBOulet connect that constraint. Then detect device and set value for this constraint

Answer (score 0):

In IB use size class wRhR size class for ipad. For iPad there is no separate size class for landscape mode and portrait mode. You can do it using progarmatically using outlets.

There is way to do it in IB if you override trait collections in your code and override any size class relevant to you.